# Shorten sequence of if statements

Tags: python, coding-style, if-statement

I have this code.

```
c = getch()
if c == "r":                                                                   
  return randrange(101, len(mylist) - 1) 
if c == "u":                                                        
  return 100               
if c == "b":      
  return -2                
if c == "w":    
  return -3                
if c == "m":
  return -4                
if c == "d":
  return -5                
if c == "e":
  return -6                
if c == "k":
  return -7
if c == "g":
  return -8
if c == "p":
  return -9
if c == "o":
  right = center - 1       
else:                      
  left = center + 1
```

Can I make this code snippet more compact? How would you write it better?

thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a dictionary:

```
# Special case.
if c == "r":                                                                   
    return randrange(101, len(list) - 1) 

# This is constant. It could be generated once at program start.
d = { 'u' : 100, ...., 'p' : -9 }

# This covers the majority of the cases.
if c in d:
    return d[c]

# Some more special cases.
if c == "o":
   right = center - 1       
else:                      
   left = center + 1
```

Comment: You could also have `'r': randrange(101, len(list) -1)` as a member of the dictionary, if you're not concerned about the added overhead of having to call randrange and len even when c != 'r'

Comment: @Kevin: Thta would lead to every access with `'r'` getting the same number. Not a difference when you create the dictionary on each call, but that requires the dictionary to be defined in the function (as opposed to... anywhere else, like in a config file or programatically from some other input). It's also unnecessary and would be slightly wasteful.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that a dictionary is the way to go.  The problem with Mark's answer is that the dictionary gets rebuilt for every function call.  The way around is to define the dict outside the function:

```
def foo():
    c = getch()
    if c in foo.mydict:
        return foo.mydict[c]
    else:
        # TODO: special cases

foo.mydict = {'u':100, ... , 'p':-9}

# foo is now ready to use
```

Answer (score 1):

You should strongly consider renaming your `list` variable to something that isn't already used.

```
...
c=getch()
if c=="r":
    return randrange(101, len(mylist) - 1)

return dict(u=100, b=-2, w=-3, m=-4, d=-5, e=-6, k=-7, g=-8, p=-9, o=center-1).get(c, center+1)
```

Comment: It had non-english name. I had to rename it.